# One equation: Two lines?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am a math student and I remember seeing an equation that graphed literally two parallel lines with one equation. Does anyone have any idea what it may look like?

Comment: $x=\pm k$ for $k>0$?

Comment: Even better: $x^2=k^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Try an equation of the form  $(y-mx-c_1)(y-mx-c_2)=0$

Answer (score 2):

You can get two parallel lines with $|y-x|=1$ or more simply by $|x|=1$.  You can get two crossing lines with $(y-x-1)(y+2x+2)=0$

Answer (score 2):

A general form for the equation of a line is
$$
Ax + By + C = 0.
$$
Unlike the function graph $y=mx+b,$ this more general form works even if the line is vertical.

To get *two* lines, just write each line in the form above and multiply the left-hand sides:
$$
(A_1x + B_1y + C_1)(A_2x + B_2y + C_2) = 0.
$$
To get parallel lines, use the same coefficient for $x$ each time
(that is, $A_1 = A_2$) and likewise for $y$ (let $B_1= B_2$),
and change only the constant value (let $C_1 \neq C_2$).